# Accept and check for any specific client certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

How to accept only specific client certificate in ASP.Net / IIS7. For example client may have 3 certificates (CertificateX,CertificateY,CertificateZ). My ASP.Net application should automatically should check and accept the CertificateY.